# Get Call logs Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

**What i want**

Hi, I am new to BB development and want to know how can i get all call logs list with attributes like time, number etc programmatically ??

**What i Read**

i have read this [Link](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Retrieve_call_history_565563_11.jsp)  but not getting the way to implement.
Also there is not good support like android or iOS for blackberry.

Kindly suggest me with some code snippet.
Thanks

Comment: Sir whats the issue in that link..??

Comment: what is your target - java blackberries or bb 10?

Comment: @EugenMartynov its Java BlackBerry

Comment: @SilentKiller it is java in the link, but what is target for the topic starter?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you really do want Java (BBOS) code.

In my opinion, the link you referenced provides sufficient information to code something, but since you seem to need more, I hope this helps:

```
PhoneLogs _logs = PhoneLogs.getInstance();
int numberOfCalls = _logs.numberOfCalls(PhoneLogs.FOLDER_NORMAL_CALLS);
System.out.println("Number of calls: " + Integer.toString(numberOfCalls));
for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfCalls; i++ ) {
    PhoneCallLog phoneLog = (PhoneCallLog)_logs.callAt(i,PhoneLogs.FOLDER_NORMAL_CALLS);
    int callType = phoneLog.getType();
    String callTypeString = "";
    switch (callType) {
    case PhoneCallLog.TYPE_MISSED_CALL_OPENED:
    case PhoneCallLog.TYPE_MISSED_CALL_UNOPENED:
        callTypeString = "Missed";
        break;
    case PhoneCallLog.TYPE_PLACED_CALL:
        callTypeString = "Placed";
        break;
    case PhoneCallLog.TYPE_RECEIVED_CALL:
        callTypeString = "Received";
        break;
    default:
        callTypeString = "Unknown";
        break;
    }
    PhoneCallLogID participant = phoneLog.getParticipant();
    System.out.println("Call: " + Integer.toString(i) + " " + callTypeString + " " + participant.getAddressBookFormattedNumber());
}
```

Sample output (from debug log):

```
Number of calls: 1
Call: 0 Placed 1 (234) 534-5343 5555
```